# Flink customized Tuple with null value

Tags: java, apache-flink

I have my customized tuple for conveying the data between operators.

```
public class A extends Tuple2<String, Message> {

    public String topic;

    public A() {
        super();
    }

    public A(String topic, String key, Message message) {
        super(key, message);
        this.topic = topic;
    }

    public String getTopic() {
        return topic;
    }

    public String getCellId() {
        return this.f0;
    }

    public Message getMessage() {
        return this.f1;
    }
}
```

But the `getTopic()` returns null when I try to get it in the downstream operator. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning topic field to itself:

```
 public A(String topic, String key, Message message) {
        super(key, message);
        this.topic = topic; //<-bug
    }
```

I think you need to implement [Tuple3<T0,T1,T2>](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/api/java/tuple/Tuple3.html)

Comment: Thanks. I think so. But there are reasons I need to use Tuple2. I end up making the `topic` public helps resolve the issue. I think it relates to the Flink serializing strategy with the Tuple class and other classes. But I don't know why...